# Query doesn't update table when it is run form Python code

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

When I run a query from `sqlite browser` the table get updated but when I use same query from `Python` the database won't get updated:

```
def updateDB (number, varCheck=True):

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()

    i = 1
    for each_test in number:
        c.execute("UPDATE table1 SET val='%s' WHERE amount='%s' AND rank='%s'" % (each_test , str(i), 'rank2'))
        i += 1
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return True
```

How can I fix the issue? I run python code as `sudo`.

Comment: somewhere you are using `%s` and somewhere `'%s'` ? any explanations?

Comment: Thanks @anmol_uppal. I have update my question. Still same problem.

Comment: is number a list/tuple of strings ?

Comment: yes it is, e.g. ----> [1, 5, 2, 0, 1]

Comment: But that's a list of integers and not strings.

Comment: I have added %d, but I still can't see change in DB.

Comment: if the column [val] in your table is defined as an integer, then feeding it a string value (enclosed in quotes `'%s', or `'%d'`) will cause the sql statement to error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I had similar issues while creating sql queries. I doubt if your sql query is being correctly formatted. The % string interpolation method can be a problem. Try using the .format() on the sql query string. [PEP3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) explains the same about using .format() instead of % operator for string interpolation.

```
val='"' + each_test + '"'
amount = '"' + str(i) + '"'
rank= '"' + "rank2" + '"'
sql_qeury = "UPDATE table1 SET val={val} WHERE amount={amount} AND rank={rank}".format(val=val,amount=amount,rank=rank)
```